# How do I map through a variable in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was using react-tree-graph and I was creating a data object but I want to use my backend api to fill in the properties of the data object. I tried using the .map method to loop through my api but I couldnt figure out how to get it to work. Here's the data object and below is my object from my api.

```
let data =  { 
    name: 'Water',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Earth',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Air',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Fire',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 'Fire2',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'Air2',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Fire3',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 'Fire4',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        name: 'Earth2',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Air3',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Fire5',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 'Fire6',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'Air4',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Fire7',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 'Fire8',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

Instead of the strings I want to map through this variable and fill it in with object as such

```
flower= {water: "name1",air: "name2",air2: "name3",air3: "name4",air4: "name5",earth: "name6",earth2: "name7",fire: "name8",fire2: "name9",fire3: "name10",fire4: "name11",fire5: "name12",fire6: "name13",fire7: "name14",fire8: "name15"}
```

I just wanted to know how I could use this object and map through it to fill in the different properties inside the data object

Comment: This isn't really a React question; you might want to re-tag it. Also please show what you've tried - the example map code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you question, Ive worked with recursive.

```js
    let data =  { 
        name: 'Water',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Earth',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Air',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Fire',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Fire2',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'Air2',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Fire3',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Fire4',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },

          {
            name: 'Earth2',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Air3',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Fire5',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Fire6',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'Air4',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Fire7',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Fire8',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
    let counter = 1;
    function recursiveNaming(data) {
        return data.children.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        let obj;
        let currentObj = {...acc, [curr.name]:`name${counter++}`};
        if(curr.children.length) {
            obj = recursiveNaming(curr);
        }
        return {...currentObj, ...obj  };
      },{})
    };

    console.log(recursiveNaming(data))
```

Hope it worth it....